# Finding a node in an XML document by its attribute value

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to grab a value from a xml feed, but I am not sure how to get it.
Feed:

```
 <name>
    <namerecord nameID="0" platformID="1" platEncID="0" langID="0x0">
      Hello World
    </namerecord>
    <namerecord nameID="1" platformID="1" platEncID="0" langID="0x0">
      MyName
    </namerecord>
    <namerecord nameID="6" platformID="1" platEncID="0" langID="0x0">
      Another Record
    </namerecord>
    <namerecord nameID="12" platformID="1" platEncID="0" langID="0x0">
      Another Record Again
    </namerecord>
```

I am trying to grab the items from that, by target what is the value of nameID. If I target it just by like namerecord[0] its not correct in the way I need it.

I have tried numerous things like:

```
$test = $xml->name->namerecord->attributes('nameId, '12');
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

That's now how you handle XML:

```
$dom = new DOM();
$dom->load('your xml here');

$xp = new XPath($dom);

$node = $xp->query('//namerecord[@nameID=12]')->item(0);

$nameID = $node->getAttribute('nameID');
```

Comment: Not sure what that DOM() class is, and its not working in php5. I thought simpleXML was the best way to work with XML in php?

Comment: http://php.net/dom   perhaps it's not enabled on your install, or bundled as a separate package. SimpleXML is ok, but think of it as "DOM-lite"